# Python - Incorrect assignment of functions within a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I'm trying to simply some of my code by using dictionaries to contain and index functions related to certain calculations. I have run into a problem where the functions in the dictionary become muddled and behave unpredictably.

This illustrates the issue I'm having...

```
def y_at_x_first(x):
    return x * 1.0

def y_at_x_second(x):
    return x * 2.0

things = {
    'first': {
        'y_at_x': lambda x: y_at_x_first(x)
    },
    'second': {
        'y_at_x': lambda x: y_at_x_second(x)
    },
}

for thing in things:
    # Add a new function that makes use of the first
    things[thing]['y2_at_x'] = lambda x: things[thing]['y_at_x'](x)


numbers = list(range(5))

print('first',
      list(map(things['first']['y_at_x'], numbers)),
      ' = ',
      list(map(things['first']['y2_at_x'], numbers)))

print('second',
      list(map(things['second']['y_at_x'], numbers)),
      ' = ',
      list(map(things['second']['y2_at_x'], numbers)))
```

I'm expecting it to print:

```
first [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]  =  [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
second [0.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0]  =  [0.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0]
```

But what it actually prints is a random choice between:

```
first [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]  =  [0.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0]
second [0.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0]  =  [0.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0]
```

and

```
first [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]  =  [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
second [0.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0]  =  [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

It is literally a random choice, run the code multiple times and it changes (I assume its to do with the dictionary not being ordered, so the randomness comes from  that).
I thought this must be an issue with my references so I tried surrounding all function references with `copy.deepcopy()`, but the problem persists.

Any help is much appreciated.
I know other ways of doing what I'm trying to achieve, but I wanted to know if this is a problem with my understanding or with Python.
Interestingly, in Python3 the result is random; in  Python2 the result is always the second option (with 4.0 as element 4).

Comment: Do note that `'y_at_x': lambda x: y_at_x_first(x)` could be done more efficiently as `'y_at_x': y_at_x_first` (removes an extra function call layer).

Comment: Yes, thanks. The example is heavily simplified, in reality the function I'm assigning is a combination of many other things.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this code here:

```
for thing in things:
    # Add a new function that makes use of the first
    things[thing]['y2_at_x'] = lambda x: things[thing]['y_at_x'](x)
```

You're using `thing` inside the lambda function but Python won't "store" this value inside the lambda function for later. For example, if I change `thing` to something else it'll use that value for `thing` when you call the function:

```
>>> thing = 'foo'
>>> things['first']['y2_at_x'](3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <lambda>
KeyError: 'foo'
```

You can avoid the issue by making sure you're using `thing` as intended (i.e., at the time that for loop is running it'll have the appropriate value):

```
for thing in things:
    # Add a new function that makes use of the first
    f = things[thing]['y_at_x']  # thing will have the value of the key here
    things[thing]['y2_at_x'] = lambda x: f(x)
```

By accessing the function object in the loop it's clear what object you're using and you can then call it in the lambda function.

The randomness that you're seeing indeed has to do with the fact that dictionaries are unordered and as such it's not known whether `first` or `second` comes first.

Comment: Thanks Simeon. So how would I go about setting 'thing' inside the lambda definition so that it always points to the right 'thing'?

Comment: I tried your example of setting `f = things[thing]['y_at_x']` and I still get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

As Semeon stated:

> You're using thing inside the lambda function but Python won't "store"
>   this value inside the lambda function for later.

So I need a way to set the value of thing inside the lambda function.
By wrapping the assignment with the `exec()` function I can have Python 'type' the correct string inside the lambda function.

```
for thing in things:
    exec("things[thing]['y2_at_x'] = lambda x: things['"+thing+"']['y_at_x'](x)")
```

This solves the problem, but I feel that using an exec statement isn't the most elegant solution. If anybody has a better solution I'd love to hear it.